# Prevent Updating createdAt field each time flush entity

Tags: symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2 doctrine orm to update record. But each time updating record, TIMESTAMP field called createdAt value is changing ( set current date time ). How to prevent this behavior? see my code,

```
    public function newsDetailsAction(Request $request)
        {  

         ....

        $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:BlogPostEntity')->findOneBy(array('postId' =>  $postid ));  

        $views = $post->getPostViews();

        $post->setPostViews($views + 1);

                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($post);
                $entityManager->flush(); 

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Bad. I was using timestamp for type. That's the issue.